# How can I properly fix this existing drywall corner (ceiling to wall)?

Tags: mudding

In the picture below 1 and 2 are existing painted drywall sheets (2 resulted from the removal of the 3 sheet, I guess it was a fill in strip since 3 is 8' long). I did not remove 2 because I did not need to and I thought it would save me time to finish that corner later

-(2) and (3) are on the ceiling
-(1) is the existing wall
-(2) is a little under 6" wide

The new sheet (3) is now forming a hump where it butt joins (2) .I would like to build up mud under (2) in order to rebuild the horizontal and hide that hump

It is clear for me that I need to scratch the surface of the paint before adding mud there
What is not clear is if I need to rebuild the entire corner (which means mudding and tapping both sides) or it is enough to just build mud under (2) till it reaches (4) the horizontal line
So do I need to tap/retap that corner ?

[image]

Comment: #2 goes up when approaching the corner, or down? How much? If it's more than about 1in, then re-panel it or add a panel to build it up, then fill, otherwise just fill it. Use "setting type" compound. Will not shrink and hardens fast (does not dry), and can be applied directly to painted surfaces.

Comment: Yes (2)goes up, around a 1/4"